# How to make git describe use semver compatible tags only

Tags: git, glob, semantic-versioning, git-describe

I want my `git describe` invocation to use only refs
that conform to [semantic versioning](https://semver.org).
To keep it simple, for now, I do not care about other options
(like annotated tags only, branches, candidates, ...).

Example:

I have tagged an early/old commit with `1.1.1` (semver compatible),
a more recent commit with `my-software-2.2.2`,
and an even newer one with `some-random-tag`.
I want my `git describe` invocation to only consider the `1.1.1` tag.

The main difficulty here,
seems to be that the way to limit the tags by their name is based on [globs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html),
not regex.

Answer (score 3):

The best option I found so far:

```bash
git describe \
    --match='[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*' \
    --exclude='*[^0-9.]*'
```

Because the `--match` flag only supports primitive globs,
not full regex,
this check only considers very simple semver's of the form `integer.integer.integer`,
disregarding other valid ones, like:

- `2.0.0-rc.2`
- `2.0.0-rc.1`
- `1.0.0-beta`
- `1.0.0-alpha+001`
- `1.0.0+20130313144700`
- `1.0.0-beta+exp.sha.5114f85`
- `1.0.0+21AF26D3—-117B344092BD`

Comment: An alternative may be, to get a list of all tags, filter them with the official semver regex using grep, then invoke git describe once per such tag, using it verbatim for --match, and then somehow figure out which of the successful invocations gave the most fitting outcome ... :/

Answer (score 0):

An other option is to use the (core git independent) Go tool:
[`git-describe-semver`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/choffmeister/git-describe-semver).

sample usage:

```sh
cd my-git-directory
docker pull ghcr.io/choffmeister/git-describe-semver:latest
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/workdir ghcr.io/choffmeister/git-describe-semver:latest
```